# How to describe columns as categorical values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, describe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a mix of categorical and numeric columns. By default, `df.describe()` returns only a summary of the numerical data (describing those columns with `count`, `mean`, `std`, `min`, `quantiles`, `max`)

when iterating through all the columns in the df and describing them individually as `[df[c].describe() for c in df.columns]`  the description is returned based off of specific column dtype; i.e. numerical summary for `int` and `float` and categoric summary for `object`

Does any one know of a succinct way of describing all columns as categorical with `count`, `unique`, `top`, `freq`?

Comment: I think I answered myself while clarifying the question. just tried `df.astype('object').describe()` and it works!!

Comment: moving my comment to an answer for future reference!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

following converts all columns to `object` type then describes them:

```
df.astype('object').describe()
```

for cleaner view try:

```
df.astype('object').describe().transpose()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, for shorter code, try `T` instead of `transpose()`

Answer (score 15):

a slightly shorter version of the answer:

```
df.describe(include = 'object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if YOU want to see descriptions of all columns together(including categorical). you can use:

```
df.describe(include='all')
```